# Using AND and OR in a where clause

Tags: sql, sas

I'm having a hard time getting the correct results with this where clause.  I know it is a paraenthesis issue.  Any suggestions?

```
WHERE a.EVENT_DATE Between &trend_dt  And &enddate  
AND a.INDICATOR Not In ('INQUIRY (NOS)','PCC') 
And a.INDICATOR2 Not In ('CAT-NA','INQUIRY (NOS)') 
And d.ACTIVE In ('C','F') 
And d.ARCHIVE_STATUS in ('N','Y') 
Or (d.ARCHIVE_STATUS Is Null)
```

Thanks!

The problem with the results is that the Indicator 2 field is sometimes blank and it is only returning records where there is something in the Indictator 2 field.

This is the query:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE COMPLAINT_DATA_0 as
SELECT 
a.EVENT_DATE,
a.INDICATOR,
a.INDICATOR2,
a.COMMITTEE_ACTION AS REVIEW_TYPE,
a.LEVEL_OF_EXCEPTION AS METHOD_RECD,
a.REFER_TO AS PLAN_NTWK,
b.DESCRIPTION AS SubCategory, 
d.CROSSREF2 AS ConProvID, 
d.LAST_NAME AS Provider, 
a.MED_REC_NO AS MbrID, 
a.CONFIRMED_BY AS IndProvID, 
a.CODE_15 AS Severity, 
MAX(c.INQUIRY_BODY) AS MaxProcStep, 
e.Notes,
e.Notes2,
FROM VIPDBA.QA_PEER AS a LEFT JOIN VIPDBA.SYS_LOOKUPS AS b 
ON a.INDICATOR2=b.CODE 
LEFT JOIN VIPDBA.QA_PEER_INQUIRY AS c 
     ON a.LOOKUP_KEY=c.LOOKUP_KEY AND 
a.MED_REC_NO=c.MED_REC_NO 
LEFT JOIN VIPDBA.MASTER_CRED AS d 
    ON a.LOOKUP_KEY=d.LOOKUP_KEY 
LEFT JOIN Complaint_Notes AS e 
    ON a.LOOKUP_KEY=e.LOOKUP_KEY AND 
a.MED_REC_NO=e.MbrID
WHERE a.EVENT_DATE Between &trend_dt  And &enddate  
    AND a.INDICATOR Not In ('INQUIRY (NOS)','PCC') 
    And a.INDICATOR2 Not In ('CAT-NA','INQUIRY (NOS)') 
    And d.ACTIVE In ('C','F') 
    And 
        ( d.ARCHIVE_STATUS IN ('N','Y') 
        OR d.ARCHIVE_STATUS is null)
GROUP a.EVENT_DATE, 
a.INDICATOR,
a.INDICATOR2,
b.DESCRIPTION, 
d.CROSSREF2, 
d.LAST_NAME, 
a.MED_REC_NO, 
a.CONFIRMED_BY, 
a.CODE_15, 
e.Notes,
e.Notes2,
d.archive_status,
d.active
ORDER BY 
a.EVENT_DATE, 
a.INDICATOR2, 
b.DESCRIPTION, 
d.CROSSREF2, 
d.LAST_NAME
```

;
   run;

Comment: Some guidance as to what you are expecting and what you are getting would probably help.

Comment: you have some left joins before this ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What Ouput are you expecting? Also can you paste the entire Query

Comment: Yes I do have some left joins.

Comment: The `d.ACTIVE In ('C','F')` in the where caluse will make the left join behave like an ordinary join. (so you will need the `OR d.active IS NULL` construct here, too)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```
WHERE a.EVENT_DATE Between &trend_dt  And &enddate  
AND a.INDICATOR Not In ('INQUIRY (NOS)','PCC') 
And a.INDICATOR2 Not In ('CAT-NA','INQUIRY (NOS)') 
And d.ACTIVE In ('C','F') 
And ( d.ARCHIVE_STATUS in ('N','Y') Or d.ARCHIVE_STATUS Is Null )
```

Use parenthesis to group logic together.

Answer (score 2):

A trick to avoid the checking-for NULL (and thus avoiding the need for an `OR ...`) is to transform the NULL to a comparable value, like in:

```
WHERE a.EVENT_DATE BETWEEN &trend_dt AND &enddate  
AND a.INDICATOR NOT IN ('INQUIRY (NOS)','PCC') 
AND a.INDICATOR2 NOT IN ('CAT-NA','INQUIRY (NOS)') 
AND d.ACTIVE IN ('C','F') 
AND COALESCE(d.ARCHIVE_STATUS, 'N') IN ('N','Y') 
   ;
```

Comment: This will still break the ability to use an index on the archive_status column, but it is a little better than the OR condition

Answer (score 2):

Or you can even avoid using OR :)

```
WHERE a.EVENT_DATE Between &trend_dt  And &enddate  
AND a.INDICATOR Not In ('INQUIRY (NOS)','PCC') 
And a.INDICATOR2 Not In ('CAT-NA','INQUIRY (NOS)') 
And d.ACTIVE In ('C','F') 
And COALESCE(d.ARCHIVE_STATUS,'-1') in ('N','Y','-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you need to see results where d.ARCHIVE_STATUS in ('N','Y') 
Or (d.ARCHIVE_STATUS Is Null) if so, you will probably just need to change it to look like this

```
WHERE a.EVENT_DATE Between &trend_dt  And &enddate  
AND a.INDICATOR Not In ('INQUIRY (NOS)','PCC') 
And a.INDICATOR2 Not In ('CAT-NA','INQUIRY (NOS)') 
And d.ACTIVE In ('C','F') 
And (
      d.ARCHIVE_STATUS in ('N','Y') 
      Or 
      d.ARCHIVE_STATUS Is Null
    )
```

This way it will only evaluate d.ARCHIVE_STATUS in ('N','Y') against d.ARCHIVE_STATUS Is Null